# File uploads and client_max_body_size in nginx + gunicorn + django

Tags: nginx, django, upload, gunicorn

I need to configure nginx + gunicorn to be able to upload files greater than the default max size in both servers.

My nginx .conf file looks like this:

```
server {
    # ...

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect   off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme  $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 60;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    }
}
```

The idea is to allow requests of 20M for two locations:

- `/admin/path/to/upload?param=value`
- `/installer/other/path/to/upload?param=value`

I've tried to add `location` directives at the same level than the one I've pasted here (getting 404 errors) and also tried to add them inside the `location /` directive (getting `413 Entity Too Large` errors).

My location directives look like these in their simplest form:

```
location /admin/path/to/upload/ {
    client_max_body_size 20M;
}
location /installer/other/path/to/upload/ {
    client_max_body_size 20M;
}
```

But they don't work (actually I tested lots of combinations and I'm desperate thinking about this.

Please, help If you can: What settings do I need to set to make this work?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This finally worked doing something like this:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect   off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme  $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol ssl;
    proxy_connect_timeout 120;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;

    location /admin/path/to/upload {
        client_max_body_size 50m;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/admin/path/to/upload;
    }
}
```

Comment: client_max_body_size 0M; will remove size restrictions

Comment: Thank you for the answer :-) Will be useful for other people.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it was almost working when you had the `client_max_body_size` in the non-root locations. Have you also set `dav_methods  PUT;` in your nginx conf to enable PUT and DELETE requests?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @chrskly. The method used to upload the files is POST so I think there is no need for adding the `dav_methods` setting. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.